# .net core raspberry pi 3 Error: Download failed

Tags: .net-core, raspberry-pi3

I try to follow the guide bellow to install .net core on my raspberry pi 3:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#debian

The script told me to install below:

```
dotnet_install: Error: Unable to locate libunwind. Install libunwind to continue
dotnet_install: Error: Unable to locate gettext. Install gettext to continue
```

i install them using apt-get install, and everything fine:

```
sudo apt-get install libunwind-dev
sudo apt-get install gettext
```

but no luck, when i run below :

```
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --version 1.0.0-preview1-002702 --install-dir ~/dotnet
```

i got:

```
dotnet_install: Error: Download failed
```

Are there any missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use last valid URL:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/rel/1.0.0-preview1/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --version 1.0.0-preview1-002702 --install-dir ~/dotnet
```

And it downloads and installs successfully on latest Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 2 (I think there should be no problem with Raspberry Pi 3).

However, after successful install, there is a error:

```
bash: dotnet: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I believe this is because of ARM architecture, because currently only amd64 (x64) is supported.